# Zend Framework 2 custom library in my controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm using ZendSkeletonApplication and I have this directory :

```
/home/mydir/vendor/My/library/My/Helper
```

which contains ff.php (respectively, `/home/mydir/vendor/My/library/My/Helper/ff.php`)

My code in `ff.php` :

```
<?php

namespace My\Helper;

class FF {
    public function test() {
        echo "success !";
    }
}
```

And my controller :

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use My\Helper\FF;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        FF::test();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

My module.php :

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'My' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/My/library/My'
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

And I get this error :`Fatal error: Class 'My\Helper\FF' not found in /home/mydir/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13`

How resolve ?

Thank you

Comment: In your controller, this can't work. You can :
set `use My\Helper\FF` and then call the class like this `FF::test()`
OR call the class without `use` like this : `\My\Helper\FF::test()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do like this in your `module.php` or `init_autoloader.php`

```
       'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'My' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/My/library/My',
            ),
        ),
```

And that will do the job :)

EDIT : And in your controller

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use My\Helper\FF;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        FF::test();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

or

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        \My\Helper\FF::test();
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done in `init_autoloader.php`, but it doesn't work : `Fatal error: Class 'My\Helper\FF' not found in /home/mydir/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13`

Comment: Try to put the code in any `module.php` in `getAutoLoaderConfig()`.

Comment: Mh. I'm sorry but doesn't work `Fatal error: Class 'My\Helper\FF' not found in /home/hub-entrepreneur/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13`
PS: I have added your code in my question

Comment: You've got the logic, now I think it's a matter of path ;).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your path is wrong.

If `init_autoloader.php` is in `/home/mydir/` and the library is in `/home/mydir/vendor/My/library/` the correct value to specify in the autoloader `namespaces` array is

`'My' => __DIR__ . '/vendor/My/library/My'`

If you handle it in the `Module::getAutoloaderConfig()` method instead (which you should, by the way), just prepend the correct sequence of `/..` to the path string, after the constant. Your mileage may vary depending on where your Module.php actually is.

Furthermore, contrary to what was stated in the other answer, you can indeed import a whole package with `use My\Helper` and then use its classes prepending just the `Helper\` prefix.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've added this `'My' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/My/library/My'`in `Module::getAutoloaderConfig()`

Comment: I dont know your directory structure, but you just have to figure out the correct relative path, how hard can it be? ;)

Answer (score 0):

create a file autoload_classmap.php in your Application Module or any module
and add in it:

```
<?php
return array(
    'FF' => 'vendor/My/library/My/Helper/ff.php', 
);
```

then you can use it anywhere in your modules like
   \FF::test()

Comment: This won't work. And the `autoload_classmap.php` is used to improve quite a little the `autoload` system, not to set it up.